parameter conversion not allowed in Mql5 expert
 if (isBullish || isBearish)
        {
            string symbolName = _Symbol;
            if (!trade.OrderSend(symbolName, orderType, LotSize, orderPrice, 10, sl, tp, "", 0, 0, clrNONE))
            {
                Print("Error placing order: ", trade.ResultRetcode());
            }
            else
            {
                PrintFormat("Order placed successfully: %s %s at price %f, SL: %f, TP: %f, Volume: %f",
                            (isBullish ? "Buy" : "Sell"), (isBullish ? "Stop" : "Stop"), orderPrice, sl, tp, LotSize);
            }
        }
    }

I have an error 'symbolName' - parameter conversion not allowed
how can solve this?
I use chat gpt to coding my strategy and I have this problem only

OrderOpen(const string symbol,const ENUM_ORDER_TYPE order_type,const double volume,const double limit_price,const double price,const double sl,const double tp,  ENUM_ORDER_TYPE_TIME type_time=ORDER_TIME_GTC,const datetime expiration=0,const string comment="") is the function you should use. try trade.OrderSend(_Symbol, orderType, LotSize, orderPrice, 10, sl, tp). in your code you have string "" for type_time argument
